# Creating a custom contact form input objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to create a well displayed contact form input using forms of some kind on Xcode, in objective-c.

The problem is that I need a good display where the user can enter the info of a contact and then save, with sections of name info, mobile info,...

> already tried:XLForm, SDForm

I have already checked XLForms and others but sadly I didn't get to make it work with my project, the manual was not that good and I am new to iOS.

I need some help implementing those libraries in my project, or any other ideas on that matter would be much appreciated.

Please note that I am using iOS 10 with Xcode 8

Answer (score 0):

Try to add libraries using Pods.
This link will give you complete idea how pods work. [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/)

its easy and you can install any library in just seconds.

Accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: i installed a library following the tutorials but when i get to creating a class like below i get a Apple Mach-O Linker Error

#import "XLFormViewController.h"

@interface AddContactViewController: XLFormViewController

end

Comment: Apple mach-O error have a lot of reasons. check your imports. there may be an error in importing . like may be you have  imported .m file instead of .h . Also do clean your project your project and build again. if that doesnt work search other options on google. There will be no error in a new project so try to practice on new project first.

Comment: yea i know but it is when i create the above that i get the error